# Call function 1 time after layout is inflated

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm making an android app that is pulling a list of objects to be displayed on the screen from a REST service.

What I need to happen is a progress dialog show while the results are being fetched.  The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure which function to put this in.  I've tried OnWindowsFocusChanged but it's being called repeatedly and the progress dialog doesn't pop up.  I've tried onCreate, onStart, onResume but they're all called before the view is inflated so nothing renders.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Thank you for any help,

Brad

Comment: If this is a fragment, you could try the `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, first of all those apis wont work for you, what you need is AsyncTask,here is what you do,

First implement AsyncTask, put all your downloading code into doInBackground(), once done.

1. display a  progress bar, right before you exceute your asynctask calling task.execute(..)
2. once your downloding form rest is complete, return your result from doInBackGround
3. Now control comes to onPostExecute of your AsyncTask, after populating your list, just dismiss the progressbar.
4. If you wish to indicate downloading percentage to user, you can do same via onProgressUpdate API to which you can push, update via doInBackground.

for more info, read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hope this help.

Comment: I would start the AsyncTask in the onCreate?

Comment: Yes, start in on create, dont do it in onResume, otherwise each time it pauses task will be started again.